# Ruby syntax for calling methods in classes

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm working on an exercise where I have to create a roman to arabic number converter.  As far as I can tell, the code below is totally kosher, but I keep getting an error when I run my tests.  Ruby thinks there's an undefined method or variable on line 37 (noted by comment below).

I'm wondering if my snytax is off or if it's something else.  Suggestions?

```
class ArabicNumeral

  def replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)
   tough_mappings = {"CM" => "DCCCC",  "CD" => "CCCC", "XC" => "LXXXX", "XL" => "XXXX", "IX"=> "VIIII", "IV" => "IIII"}
   tough_mappings.each { |roman, arabic|   letters = letters.gsub(roman, arabic) } 
   letters
  end

  def convert_and_add(letters)
    digits = { "M" => 1000, "CM" => 900, "D" => 500, "C" => 100, "XC" => 90, "L" => 50, "XL" => 40, "X" => 10, "IX" => 9, "V" => 5, "IV" =>  4, "I" => 1}
    letters = letters.split("")
    letters.inject(0) do |sum, letter|
      arabic = digits[letter]
      sum += arabic
    end  
  end

  def self.convert(letters)
    roman_string = replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)  ###LINE 37!
    arabic_number = convert_and_add(roman_string)
    arabic_number
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the method you are calling on line 37. `replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)`. The problem is the method `self.convert(letters)` is a class method. You can call it like this:

```
ArabicNumeral.convert(letters)
```

However, it contains a call to an instance variable (being that `replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)` I mentioned earlier.

```
def self.convert(letters)
    roman_string = ArabicNumeral.new.replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)
    ArabicNumeral.new.convert_and_add(roman_string)

end
```

This creates an instance of `ArabicNumeral` and calls the method you need without saving it to a variable and taking up memory. I also removed the variable `arabic_number` from your method because you are calling `convert_and_add(roman_string)`, adding it to the variable, and then returning the variable. since `convert_and_add(roman_string)` is the last thing handled by the method, it will return this anyway without the variable.

If you never plan on using those methods in an instance of `ArabicNumeral` then I would suggest making all the methods class level or wrapping them in a `Module` that you would include in your projects. If you don't plan on using them outside of the `ArabicNumeral` class at all, consider putting them behind a `protected` or `private` while leaving `convert(letters)` available.

```
class ArabicNumberal

def self.convert(letters)
   # Code...
end

private

def self.replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)
   # Code...
end

def self.convert_and_add(roman_string)
   # Code...
end

end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up bring all the methods up to "class level."  I popped "self." in front of each method name and now all my tests pass.

Answer (score 2):

Ok... First of all, you're trying to use an instance method from a class one.

The problem could be solved by changing the method convert from:

```
def self.convert(letters)
    roman_string = replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)  ###LINE 37!
    arabic_number = convert_and_add(roman_string)
    arabic_number
end
```

To:

```
def convert(letters)
    roman_string = replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)  ###LINE 37!
    arabic_number = convert_and_add(roman_string)
    arabic_number
end
```

Then you'll need to create an instance and call convert method:

```
x = ArabicalNumeral.new()
x.convert('param')
```

And that's it.

By the way, I suggest you to add a constructor method (in Ruby is named initialize).

The complete script below:

```
class ArabicNumeral

  def replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)
   tough_mappings = {"CM" => "DCCCC",  "CD" => "CCCC", "XC" => "LXXXX", "XL" => "XXXX", "IX"=> "VIIII", "IV" => "IIII"}
   tough_mappings.each { |roman, arabic|   letters = letters.gsub(roman, arabic) } 
   letters
  end

  def convert_and_add(letters)
    digits = { "M" => 1000, "CM" => 900, "D" => 500, "C" => 100, "XC" => 90, "L" => 50, "XL" => 40, "X" => 10, "IX" => 9, "V" => 5, "IV" =>  4, "I" => 1}
    letters = letters.split("")
    letters.inject(0) do |sum, letter|
      arabic = digits[letter]
      sum += arabic
    end  
  end

  def convert(letters)
    roman_string = replace_troublesome_roman_numerals(letters)  ###LINE 37!
    arabic_number = convert_and_add(roman_string)
    arabic_number
  end
end

x = ArabicNumeral.new()
puts x.convert('MDC')
```